Concentration inequality for convex hull of random samples
Let $P$ be a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $X, X_1,\ldots,X_N \sim P$ i.i.d. random vectors.
Are there any results that estimate the probability that $X \in \operatorname{conv}\{X_1,\ldots,X_N\}$ from below?
I would expect that on some reasonable assumptions on $P$ (e.g. sub-Gaussianity) one could obtain a bound that converges exponentially fast to $1$ when $N \to \infty$.
